# TCL: Regarding Mpexpr and expr command

Tags: tcl

I am using 32 bit Linux machine and  using TCL 8.5 version . when i want to calculate longer than 4 byte integers i am getting error . But i can do the same thing using "Mpexpr" package . My doubt here is , my data bus size is 32 bit but when i installed Mpexpr package i'm able to deal the 8 byte integers , How the Mpexpr works and how 32 bit databus suddenly enlarged to 64 bit . I want to know how the internal things works .

```
% set tcl_platform(wordSize)

4

%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be slightly confused. Tcl 8.5 internally uses its own arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic library (a fork of libtommath) and it should always behave as if integers are of infinite width; the *actual* representation is swapped back and forth between a C `long`, `long long` and the real arbitrary-precision type as necessary (a good thing because using native numeric types is far faster). You should never be able to write a script that observes the difference other than by using the explicit “casting” Tcl functions `int()` and `wide()`.

It was much more likely that you'd observe the issue you describe when using Tcl 8.4 (or before) where there was no built-in arbitrary-precision arithmetic support and you had to use the mpexpr package.

As for how things work, that fundamentally stems from the fact that values in Tcl do not need to be represented as system integers; there are many other possible representations. For example, a `long long` could be used and that's a 64-bit wide integer on normal 32-bit systems. For larger types, the representation is actually typically as a sequence of “digits” where each “digit” is in the range 0–255; arithmetic operations then just follow conventional rules for long addition, long multiplication, etc. just as is taught in schools. Except with rather more than ten digits to consider. (Indeed, they could use a C `unsigned short` instead of an `unsigned char` for each digit, giving a range 0–65535.) There are quite a few specialised algorithms that let you do the more advanced operations fairly quickly; I'll let you do your own literature searches…